# Rescale Large Images with JCrop

Tags: javascript, jquery, jcrop

I'm using Jcrop to crop images. I've had a problem with large images overflowing my browser window and so I followed the advise on [Jcrop's page](http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop_Sizing_Issues.html) and used the Box Sizing Method to scale large images to fit inside the cropbox. I used the example code (below) and it works well, but the issue is that I now have both the scaled image and the huge image in my browser. I would like to have only the rescaled image appear in my browser.  Any suggestions? Here's an [example](http://groovia.org/example.html) of how it displays.

```
$(function(){   
    $('#cropbox').Jcrop({ 
        boxWidth: 700, boxHeight: 700
    }); 
});

$(function(){
    $('#cropbox').Jcrop({    
        aspectRatio: 1,
        onSelect: updateCoords
    });
});

function updateCoords(c) {
    $('#x').val(c.x);
    $('#y').val(c.y);
    $('#w').val(c.w);
    $('#h').val(c.h);
};

function checkCoords() {
    if (parseInt($('#w').val())) return true;
    alert('Please select a crop region then press submit.');
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I went wrong by not merging the two cropbox functions together. When I discovered this and modified it, it works great:

```
$(function(){   
    $('#cropbox').Jcrop({
        boxWidth: 600,
        boxHeight: 600,
        aspectRatio: 1,
    onSelect: updateCoords
 });    
});
```